# AS3 - Split string

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How to allow splitting only if **_x** are the latest 2 characters in the string?

Example: **hello-world_x.jpg** should be splitted and **hello_xtra_world.jpg** not.

```
filename.text = imagename.text.split("_x").join("")
```

Thanks
Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better practice to use `replace` in combination with the RegExp @Joe-Tuskan suggested.

```
filename.text = imagename.text.replace(/_x$/, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use RegExp:

```
filename.text = imagename.text.split(/_x$/).join("")
```

---

Edit

This will work better:

```
imagename.text.replace(/(.+)_x(\.[a-z]+)/i, "$1$2");
```